# twitter 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

I am trying to import twitter data saved as text file and use the keyword function for designating columns that would show the details.

I have used this code in ipython3 notebook:

```
#definition for collecting keyword.
def word_in_text(word, text):
    word = word.lower()
    text = text.lower()
    match = re.search(word, text)
    if match:
        return True
    return False
```

The next cell has the following code:

```
#adding column
tweets['Trade'] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('Trade', tweet))
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-35-b172c4e07d29> in <module>()
  1 #adding column
----> 2 tweets['Trade'] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('Trade', tweet))

  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, 
func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
  2292             else:
  2293                 values = self.asobject
 -> 2294                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, 
  convert=convert_dtype)
  2295 
  2296         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

 pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:66124)()

<ipython-input-35-b172c4e07d29> in <lambda>(tweet)
  1 #adding column
  ----> 2 tweets['Trade'] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: 
  word_in_text('Trade', tweet))

<ipython-input-34-daa2f94a8fec> in word_in_text(word, text)
  2 def word_in_text(word, text):
  3     word = word.lower()
----> 4     text = text.lower()
  5     match = re.search(word, text)
  6     if match:

 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: The error looks pretty self explanatory. Can you provide few rows of input data so that I can try reproducing this error?

Comment: my input is coming from a text file, I have no idea how to reproduce that it has some 30,000+ tweets. and a 250 mb file

Comment: This is the code that feeds into text
`#adding 3 columns
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
tweets = json_normalize(tweet_data)[["text", "lang", "place.country","created_at", "coordinates",\
                                     "user.location"]]`

Answer (score 0):

> **Update**: I was able to reproduce your error. The field `text` might be missing in some of your tweets.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 
tweet_data = [{'text': "let's trade!", 'lang':'en', 'place': {'country':'uk'}, 'created_at':'now', 'coordinates':'x,y', 'user':{'location':'here'}}, {'lang':'en', 'place': {'country':'uk'}, 'created_at': 'now', 'coordinates':'z,w', 'user':{'location':'there'}}]
tweets = json_normalize(tweet_data)[["text", "lang", "place.country","created_at", "coordinates","user.location"]]
```

I get the error with:

```
tweets['Trade'] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('Trade', tweet))
```

Output:

```
>> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

If I feed the `tweet_data` with the 'text' key I don't get the error. So, that would be an option. Another option would be to ignore `nan` cases in your lambda.

```
tweets['Trade'] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('Trade', tweet) if type(tweet) == str else False)
```

This way you get the correct output:

```
>>> tweets
           text lang place.country created_at coordinates user.location  Trade
0  let's trade!   en            uk        now         x,y          here   True
1           NaN   en            uk        now         z,w         there  False
```

---

*This is old content, left here for completeness.*

Somehow you are passing a `float` instead of the text to your `word_in_text` method. I've tried a simple example of what you want to achieve:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def word_in_text(word, text):
    word = word.lower()
    text = text.lower()
    match = re.search(word, text)
    if match:
        return True
    return False

tweets = pd.DataFrame(['Hello, I like to trade', 'Trade', 'blah blah', 'Nice tradeoff here!'], columns=['text'])
```

The output is:

```
>>> tweets
                     text  Trade
0  Hello, I like to trade   True
1                   Trade   True
2               blah blah  False
```

Also, for this sort of task, you can always use the Pandas' str built-in `contains` method. **This code will give you the same result as the example above**:

```
tweets['Trade'] = tweets['text'].str.contains("Trade", case=False) == True
```

I guess you want to check for 'exact word' matching, meaning "Nice **trade**off here!" shouldn't be identified as containing the word. You can also solve this problem:

```
tweets['Trade_[strict]'] = tweets['text'].str.contains(r"Trade\b.*", case=False) == True
```

The output being:

```
>>> tweets
                     text  Trade  Trade_[strict]
0  Hello, I like to trade   True            True
1                   Trade   True            True
2               blah blah  False           False
3     Nice tradeoff here!   True           False
```

Plus, I added your json_normalize method with 'fake' data and it also worked. Make sure in your data you don't have any `float` in your text column instead of `str`.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 
tweet_data = [{'text': '0', 'lang':'en', 'place': {'country':'uk'}, 'created_at':'now', 'coordinates':'x,y', 'user':{'location':'here'}}, {'text': 'Trade', 'lang':'en', 'place': {'country':'uk'}, 'created_at': 'now', 'coordinates':'z,w', 'user':{'location':'there'}}]
tweets = json_normalize(tweet_data)[["text", "lang", "place.country","created_at", "coordinates","user.location"]]
```

And applying your method worked.

Comment: The problem appears to be in the code of second cell, lambda.... I have no clue on that.

Comment: great! Check the answer again, I updated it because I was able to reproduce the error. By removing the key 'text' of one of your tweets I got the exact same `float` error. Make sure that you always have this field correctly fed.

Comment: I have modified the code for multiple words but it seems to have an error `tweets['TrumpWar'] = tweets['text'].str.contains(r"Trump\b" and r"War\b", case = False) == True`

The reason I am saying so as I check the print length for `print(tweets['War'].value_counts()[True])` and `print(tweets['TrumpWar'].value_counts()[True])`,  both the queries give answer as 4807, which is factually incorrrect.

Comment: The code of the first cell has been removed entirely and I am using only what you gave me the latest code.

Comment: Okay, but that would be **another question**, out of the scope of what you asked initially. I think for correctness your first question should be marked as solved as the problem has been spotted and a solution described. As per your new question, about filtering by multiple words, I'm not gonna dive deeply into it. but you can always make the regular expression as complex as you want. This should work: `tweets['TrumpWar'] = tweets['text'].str.contains(r"^(?=.*\btrump\b)(?=.*\bwar\b).*$", case=False) == True
`

Answer (score 0):

```
def word_in_text(word, text):
    word = word.lower()
    text = text.lower()
    match = re.search(word, text)
    if match:
        return True
    return False

tweets['Trade'] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('Trade', tweet))
```

ERROR:

```
<ipython-input-34-daa2f94a8fec> in word_in_text(word, text)
  2 def word_in_text(word, text):
  3     word = word.lower()
----> 4     text = text.lower()
  5     match = re.search(word, text)
  6     if match:
```

You need to check whether the text parameter is of type str . So either check it with if else as shown in the answer by @Guiem Bosch. 
Else simply convert the type of the text parameter by :

```
text = type(text).lower()
```

Hope this helps.